# Image of God of Time

Tags: greek

In the [Time for Chronos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319020/275467), I wrote some code that uses the chrono library to measure the time needed for an image of God of time Chronos to be displayed in ASCII art. However, I am not sure about the image.

Poseidon holds the trident, Zeus the lighting and so on. Does Chronos have any distinctive "item" or anything on his pose that would distinguish him from the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the post of God of Time, I was told that he usually holds a [Zodiac Wheel](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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) and/or a [Scythe](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWypgGrCDLfJ3kLwIKBlQDdJKdmA71Q1ZzdWY7vSWpu88BUMdP2A) (reminds me of a modern Hades with this one).